# Immediate lookup of value in a hash table defined as a literal

Tags: powershell, hashtable

What is the shortest and nicest way to have a hash table literal and instantly look up a value in it?

e.g. I was expecting something like

```
$city = @{"30328" = "Atlanta"; "60608" = "Chicago"} [$zipCode]
```

but that ends with:

> Unexpected token '[$zipCode]' in expression or statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the space:

```
$city = @{"30328" = "Atlanta"; "60608" = "Chicago"}[$zipCode]
```

or

```
$city = @{"30328" = "Atlanta"; "60608" = "Chicago"}.$zipCode
```

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't even thought. Is there any reason for such strictness in the syntax here? I am having hard time recalling in what other language I would see a thing like this.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki actually powershell can be quite forgiving in its syntax, especially in terms of whitespace; this just happens to not be one of those times. With an array or hashtable, even when it's in a variable, you can't put whitespace between the variable and the indexer (same goes for `.`).

Comment: As to "what other language" - I just stumbled open http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229022/why-sort-ls-l-works-and-sort-ls-l-failed which is a bit different thing, still an added whitespace causing invalid syntax.